# Open view in a new tab - grails

Tags: grails

I have a URL, and then the user clicks on the following i need this URL to be opened in a new Tab. How can i do this.

The URL i want to open is `http://lhost/pro/app/showusers?p=0&u=90`

My Grails code look as follows: How can i open the above link that will open in a new tab

```
<td><g:link action="showusers" id="${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "name")}">${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "name")}</g:link></td>
```

Update :

When i click on the above link i get `http://lhost/pro/app/showusers/5` as the URL but i want to display `http://lhost/pro/app/showusers?p=0&u=90` as the URL. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the `target` attribute of the link element you can do this. You can give the tab/window a name or use `_blank` and allow the browser to assign a new name internally. Using the same name will target the same window/tab if it's already open.

Most (if not all) Grails standard tags will echo any additional attributes as HTML element attributes when present.

For example:

```
<td><g:link action="showusers" id="${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "name")}" target="_blank">${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "name")}</g:link></td>
```

You can read more about the link/href element [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp).

Comment: Thanks. This answers one part of my question. I have updated my question above. Can you please help me sort this out.

Comment: Can you explain what `p` and `u` are and where they come from? That way I can update with an example of using the `params` attribute?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `<g:link action="showusers" id="${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "name")}" target="_blank" params="[p:0, u:90]">`?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Obviously using `params` is the correct way to accomplish this, however @lllep never responded to my question here in the comments about what `p` and `u` are so I didn't want to assume they were just constant values. I think they figured it out based on my mentioning `params`.

Comment: Of course the values (or the names) wouldn't have to be constants.  I assume that the asker would know that.